# Mongoose, correct method to access instance fields inside instance method

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to implement an instance function on a Model. It checks whether a model instance's value for the field `expiresAt` is beyond a particular timestamp. This is my schema

```
let MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   userId : { type : ObjectId , unique : true, required: true },
   provider : { type : String, required : true},
   expiresAt : { type : Number, required : true}
},{ strict: false });
```

This is the instance method

```
MySchema.methods.isExpired = () => {
    console.log(this.expiresAt) // undefined
    return ( this.expiresAt < (Date.now()-5000) )
};
```

But the value for `this.expiredAt` is undefined. Then I tried to rewrite the function as follows

```
MySchema.methods.isExpired = () => {
   try{
       console.log(this._doc.expiresAt);
       console.log((Date.now()-5000));
       return (this._doc.expiresAt < (Date.now()-5000));
   } catch (e){
       console.error(e);
   }
};
```

This causes an exception

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'expiresAt' of undefined` for the line `console.log(this._doc.expiresAt);`

What is the correct method to access instance fields inside the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in your method, which changes the binding of `this` value.

Definition with `function() {}` of your mongoose methods, keep `this` value to your instance.

```
MySchema.methods.isExpired = function() {
    console.log(this.expiresAt) // is now defined
    return ( this.expiresAt < (Date.now()-5000) )
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @drinchev, I didn't know about the status of this in arrow functions

Comment: I instinctively made an arrow function and forgot about this side effect.